# Where do I enable symbol levels?

Tags: qgis-3, symbology

From [the help](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html#moderate-fa-ordering-symbol-levels), to enable symbol levels I should tick "Enable symbol levels":

[image]

but there is none in my QGIS (3.20.2-Odense):
[image]

How do I enable it, I need to draw my red symbol on top of the green? I'm using rule based symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to set Symbol Levels with Rule-based symbols. To have what you are looking for you must be in "categorized" mode.

Change rule set to categorized in symbology option:

[image]

Comment: change rule set to categorized in symbology option